# Function parameter

Tags: python, pandas

----Updated code---

I have problems with the following code

```
df = pd.read_csv('Fifa20.csv')    
selector = df[['Name', 'Overall', 'Skill', 'Dribbling', 'Curve']]

def get_player(player):
    selector.loc[selector['Name'] == player]

    return selector[['Overall', 'Skill', 'Dribbling', 'Curve']].sum(axis=1) / len(selector.columns)
```

I was working a bit with the fifa20 dataset from kaggle, and wanted to make a dynamic function, which take the players name and then give me a number based on their skillset. I cannot figure out how to connect the two parts in my functions, so if I call my function with "Lionel Messi" it will return the calculated number.

Could you guide me or give me a hint, to how I should think and connect the two ? At this moment, I think I am overthinking it quite a bit.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "connet the two parts in my function"? What two parts? Also, what is `selector`? Where is it defined and what value does it have? Please provide a [mcve] that we can run ourselves to see what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have updated my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include the dataframe as well as a function parameter. This should work fine-

```
df = pd.read_csv('Fifa20.csv')    
selector = df[['Name', 'Overall', 'Skill', 'Dribbling', 'Curve']]
player = 'Lionel Messi'

def get_player(player, selector):
    # Subsets selector to contain specific player's information
    selector = selector.loc[selector['Name'] == player]
    return selector[['Overall', 'Skill', 'Dribbling', 'Curve']].sum(axis=1) / len(selector.columns)
```

This function takes the player name and dataframe as input and returns the desired value.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I have some troubles understanding, what the input of 'selector' should be in the function ?

Comment: `selector` is your dataframe which contains player's information.

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot get my head around the meaning. So it would be something like this? - get_player('Lionel Messi', selector) ? Because player is defined as the name in my dataframe, where selector is the skill-set. How can selector be parameter ? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you can pass the player name like this. Can you provide a sample of your dataframe in the question? It'd be really helpful.

Comment: Yes! I just updated my code. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you! However, I still cannot get my head around what to write as parameter for selector. My conclusion is that I am missing out on something working with functions. But I believe your solution is right, no doubt

Comment: Jesus, now I get it. Thank you @Shradha!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

Assuming you have loaded your dataset in `selector`dataframe.
Then,

1. Select that row with the player name.
2. Apply sum on the skills feature and divide it by count of skills

   ```
   def get_player(player):
    global selector 
    player_row = selector.loc[selector['Name'] == player]

    return player_row[['Overall', 'Skill', 'Dribbling', 'Curve']].sum(axis=1) / len(player_row.columns)
   ```